# Testing for null object using short-circuit logical operator

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment, logical-operators, control-structure

I'm reading through the [Mozilla Developer Network's page on Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript#Control_structures), and am confused by a line I see. Here's the description and line in question:

> The && and || operators use short-circuit logic, which means whether they will execute their second operand is dependent on the first. This is useful for checking for null objects before accessing their attributes:

```
var name = o && o.getName();
```

My confusion here is that, presumably the purpose of the snippet is to perform:

```
var name;
if (o){
     name = o.getname();
}
```

However, it looks like what happens here is that name is being assigned a boolean, and that boolean is "o exists and its name is not empty". In other words, to me it looks like:

```
var name = false;
if (o && o.getname()){
    name = true;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [**Logical Operators**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators), at the very top: *"Logical operators are typically used with Boolean (logical) values; when they are, they return a Boolean value. However, the && and || operators actually return the value of one of the specified operands, so if these operators are used with non-Boolean values, they may return a non-Boolean value."*

Comment: In short, `&&` returns its leftmost falsy operand, or the last one if all those are truthy, and `||` - the leftmost truthy operand, or the last one if all those are falsy.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Yes, the snippet does something, but to you, it should do something else. Then, what is the question? *Why?* Because that is how it is compiled...

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon The description above didn't make it clear, and is all I had to go on, so I wasn't sure if it actually did result in name being a boolean or if there were some behavior of && I wasn't aware of.

Comment: @JoshLemer Ok so Felix Kling answered that question right?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Yep!

Comment: @raina77ow So what would `var name = o && o.getName();` return if `o` is indeed empty? If the comparison returned the left-most falsy operand it would be `o` which is an empty object. So `name` would become an empty object? In my test it became `undefined` instead. Can you explain why?

Comment: @philmcole Define 'empty'. Empty object (`{}`) is truthy actually, btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This answer is the comment of [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) and I hope that he will post it as his own answer to get the rewarded reputation*

---

Have a look at [Logical Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators), at the very top:

> "Logical operators are typically used with Boolean (logical) values; when they are, they return a Boolean value. However, the && and || operators actually return the value of one of the specified operands, so if these operators are used with non-Boolean values, they may return a non-Boolean value."