# Linked List Palindrome Leet Code Solution in Javascript

Tags: javascript, singly-linked-list

I have looked up the solution for the palindrome question in Javascript.

There is a line of code that I dont really understand and I hope someone can enlighten me.

Here is the solution:

```
this.palindrom = function() {
            //two pointers to find the middle 
            // 1 slow pointer - move 1 at a time
            // 1 fast pointer - move 2 at a time 

        let slow = this.head
        let fast = this.head
        let start = this.head
        console.log('fast', fast)
        let length = 0 
       
        while( fast && fast.next) {
            fast = fast.next.next
            slow = slow.next 
            start = start.next
            length++
        }
        console.log(slow)
       let mid = this.reverse(slow)
        console.log('mid',mid)
        while (length !== 0) {
            length --
            if (mid.data !== start.data) return false 
            else return true 
        }

      }
    }
```

I do not understand why the parameters of the "while" loop is

`while( fast && fast.next)`

i typed while(fast.next) and there was an error saying cannot access null of next. I am wondering why fast && fast.next works instead.

Comment: because `fast` might be null and in that case the expression `fast.next` would throw a null reference exception. Instead using `fast && fast.next`, `fast.next` gets evaluated partecipating to the AND condition only if fast is not null.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Testing for null object using short-circuit logical operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23345029/testing-for-null-object-using-short-circuit-logical-operator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fast && fast.next` is applying a safeguard to `fast` being `null`. If `fast` is `null`, then it would be an error to evaluate `fast.next` -- which is what you experienced when you "simplified" the condition.

If `fast` is `null` then the expression `fast` will be "falsy", and because of how the `&&` operator works (short-circuiting), the evaluation will then stop and not attempt to evaluate `fast.next`. Instead it will consider the whole expression to be falsy, and exit the loop.